# Curl not working when URL has parameters

Tags: ruby, curl, web-scraping

I use `Curl` inside a `Ruby` script to scrape this kind of page:

`https://www.example.com/page.html?a=1&b=2&c=3&d=4`

Using this code:

```
value = `curl #{ARGV[0]} | grep "findMe:"`
result = value.scan(/findMe: (.*)/).flatten.first.split('$').last.gsub(',', '').to_f
puts result
```

But since that page is using a 301 redirect, it was failing, so I added the `-L` 
attribute:

```
value = `curl -L #{ARGV[0]} | grep "findMe:"`
result = value.scan(/findMe: (.*)/).flatten.first.split('$').last.gsub(',', '').to_f
puts result
```

It now returns the result fine, but the script doesn't end. on SSH termail it is like asking me about the other parameters, after displaying result. so I must press enter to abort the script.

When I implement this in a web app, the script doesn't work, probably due to this parameter related problem.

Therefore, how I can I tell curl to abort right after displaying the result, or, to ignore any parameters in the given url, in the first place (Since they don't affect page content). So it would auto scrape this part:

`https://www.example.com/page.html`

Comment: Ruby has its own [pretty good library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html#class-Net::HTTP-label-GET+with+Dynamic+Parameters) for making http requests – is there any particular reason you're using curl?

Comment: I have Centos 6.9 and it doesn't support The Ruby version that I need to run mechanize gem, so temporarily I will use Curl until upgrade. unless there's solution that doesn't require any gems?

Comment: If it is possible please suggest a solution that can achieve the result i need with using ruby code only. I don't know Ruby at all. nor Curl very much.

Comment: which version of ruby are you using?

Comment: version is 1.9.3